# Magento Exclude Products from Shopping Cart Price Rule

Tags: php, magento

we have around 1300 shopping cart price rules. we now added a new product that we want't to exclude from all of our shopping cart price rules. what is the best way to do that? I though of updating the conditions of the shopping cart price rules programmatically, but I have no idea how to handle the serialized conditions.

thanks for your help,
michael

Answer (score 0):

if New product has one different attribute or category then you can add condition in shopping cart price rule to not include products which are from this category or attribute.

simple way you add condition in shopping cart rule use condition  "sku is not one of"  or "does not contain" then add all new product skus.

Comment: hi, that's exactly what I would like to do. but can someone help me to update existing shopping cart rules programatically as we can't update 1300 rules per hand? is there even a way to do that? thx!

Comment: refer this link http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmatically-create-apply-and-delete-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento/